# Laravel Cashier - Update card generates a new stripe user + id

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using Laravel's Cashier to handle my subscription plans on Laravel 5.1. Every time I change the user's card with

```
$user->updateCard($stripeToken);
```

a new customer is generated on Stripe, with a new card, new id but same e-mail, when in reality it should just update a customer's card. I've looked in the documentation but didn't find what could be wrong. Could someone help?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: my problem was actually kinda stupid, I was submitting for another route.. the accepted solution should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I could see that might be a possible problem is that you might be calling the method on the wrong instance. Maybe you need to do something like this?

```
$user->subscription()->updateCard($stripeToken);
```

Also, make sure that the `$user` object you're calling it on is the user you are expecting.

Here is what my method looks like when the user updates their CC details.

```
protected function updateCreditCard($creditCardToken){
    $company = Auth::user()->company;
    // subscription() is a StripeGateway object.
    $company->subscription()->updateCard($creditCardToken);
}
```